# change document title to record from db with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, title

I want to change the document title but cant get it to work.
I am working with the following code:

```
echo "<input type='textbox' id='print' value='".$row['formuliernummer']."'>";

<script type="text/javascript">
var print = document.getElementById("print");
document.title = print;
</script>
```

The formuliernummer comes from a db.

With the above code the document title becomes [object HTMLInputElement]
I have no idea what to do next!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var print = document.getElementById("print").value;
```

Comment: Thats it. Brilliant and quick. Thanks for this answer. I need to wait 12 minutes before I can accept it as the answer. Haha

Comment: I am sorry. I was forgotton to accept it. Just did it. Thanks again for the help.